# Check Role using Laratrust

Tags: php, laravel, laratrust

I get the problem when I try to check role from users table. In my case, the role user in the database is 'AdminForesell' with user ID = 9, but when I try to check it using `dd()`, the result is false, this is wrong, because in the database is true.

**The Controller**

```
public function delete($id)
    {
        $user = User::whereId($id)->first();

        dd($user->hasRole('AdminForesell'));

        if ($user->hasRole('AdminToko')) {
            File::delete('image/adminToko/logo/'. $user->store->image);
            File::delete('image/adminToko/logo/'. $user->store->banner);

            $user->store->delete();
            $user->delete();
        }
        elseif($user->hasRole('AdminForesell')) {
            Alert::error('Failed Delete', 'You cannot delete role Admin Foresell');
            return redirect('/admin-foresell/list/users');
        }
        else{
            $user->delete();

            Alert::success('Success', 'Data berhasil dihapus');
            return redirect('/admin-foresell/list/users');
        }
    }
```

**roles table**

[image]

**role_user table**

[image]

**User Table**

[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: You seem to have a discrepancy in the case of your role name, for starters.

Comment: But this authorization should be done using policies, instead of repeating this check on every controller method.